# Webhook allowing GET method

Tags: dialogflow-es

According to the documentation,

> "When an intent in which a webhook was enabled is triggered,
>   Dialogflow sends data to the service in the form of POST request with
>   a POST body in the format of response to a query."

So I assume that a GET request is not possible...isn´t it?

In Postman I am able to make a GET request using my code but after deploying to Heroku and setting the URL in the fulfillment section, I am not able to get any proper response beyond a "Webhook call failed. Error: 404 Not Found".

Thanks a lot.

Here´s the code.
This was my first attempt using Node :-)

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const http = require('https');
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

const server = express();


server.use(bodyParser.json());

server.post('/get-movie-details', function (req, res) {

    //This line is crashing the app in Heroku from Dialogflow. Paramaters are not correctly passed
    let movieToSearch = req.body.result.parameters.query;

    let finalurl = encodeURI('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=c21ed50674dabf90143d1136bf9279ae&language=en-US&query=' + req.body.result.parameters.query + '&page=1&include_adult=false');

    console.log('This is the finalUrl: ' + finalurl);

    http.get(finalurl, (responseFromAPI) => {

        responseFromAPI.on('data', function (chunk) {

            let movie = JSON.parse(chunk)['results'][0];


            let dataToSend = movie.original_title  + ' is a ' + movie.vote_average + ' vote average  released in ' + movie.release_date + '. Maybe you want some more information?';

            return res.json({
                speech: dataToSend,
                displayText: dataToSend,
                source: 'The movieDataBase'
            });

        });
    }, (error) => {
        return res.json({
            speech: 'Something went wrong!',
            displayText: 'Something went wrong!',
            source: 'get-movie-details'
        });
    });
});

 server.listen(port);
 console.log('Server started! At https://localhost:' + port);
```

Comment: If you post your code, we might be able to help you handle POST requests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct, a GET request isn't possible. The size of the JSON being sent can easily exceed the URL length allowed by GET.